# SELECT * fields order

Tags: mysql, sorting, field

Does MySQL guarantee that a query like

```
SELECT * from mytable
```

will output its fields exactly in the same order as

```
DESCRIBE mytable
```

does?

We have a rule that the first column of all tables is always the PRIMARY KEY, and while it's maybe not always a good idea to rely on the columns order in a `select *`, it would be very helpful to be sure the first field provided is the PK.

**This is a MySQL specific question** and thus not a duplicate of the link given below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [column order in SELECT \* statement - guaranteed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737232/column-order-in-select-statement-guaranteed)

Comment: @Dekel not a duplicate, it's not even the same DBMS

Comment: The answer there is is based on ANSI SQL, thought it might help a bit. I'm not sure why voting-down the question (or mark as off-topic) as I do think it's a good question.

Comment: `SELECT *` is an antipattern, so the answer *should* be "it doesn't matter."  Don't do it. It's a sloppy practice that wastes resources and defeats optimizations like covering indexes and avoidance of off-page blob reads. Select the columns you need, in the "order" you need them, and the question should be moot.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot `SELECT *` is not recommended mainly for performance and maintenance reasons. I won't enter the intimate details of what we are doing, but these queries are part of a generic set used only by administrators to request information about databases dynamically. More complex queries (via the *mysql* database) could be performed, but if MySQL would guaranty the columns order, that would simplify things, mostly for hand made quick queries by the persons in charge.

Comment: I see.  I believe MySQL *does* expand `*` in `DESCRIBE` order but I haven't posted that as an alternate answer, since I believe that to be true, primarily, because I can think of no reason why it wouldn't.  As is pointed out below, it apparently isn't documented.  The wire protocol does provide some information about keys in the result-set metadata, but it depends on what you're really trying to accomplish, whether you can do anything with this.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, mysql does not guarantee that the columns in  a `select *` will be in the same order as in `describe tablename` output. Mysql documentation does not specify the order of the columns in either case. However, both statements are likely to list columns by their ordinal positions, so in reality the outputs should match.

But even if the order of the fields were the same in both cases, this would not mean that the pk fields are listed first. You can have pk defined on any columns, not just the leftmost ones.

Comment: In the case of our structure, the rule is to have the PK as the first column, i.e. it comes first in a `DESCRIBE` command.