# Is column order guaranteed in SELECT * also within a CTE

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks-sql

This was already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11737363/8573127) for queries taking directly from a table, where there is an `ordinal_position` metadata to draw from. My question is whether the same applies for CTEs (which may or may not have their own `ordinal_position`, I genuinely do not know).

```
WITH
cte_a AS (
SELECT 
    col_a_1 AS col_1,
    col_a_2 AS col_2
FROM table_a
),

cte_b AS (
SELECT 
    col_b_1 * 10 AS col_1,
    0            AS col_2
FROM table_b
),

unioned AS (
SELECT * FROM cte_a
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cte_b
),
-- more CTEs follow
-- Ultimately, a closing SELECT follows
```

Are the two `SELECT *` above *guaranteed* to preserve the order defined in the CTEs they draw from?

Comment: My guess would be yes, but that aside doing a `SELECT *` in a union query is bad practice, as it could break as you add/subtract columns in the CTE.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Having the column list explicit in the UNION  doesn't solve the problem in the subtract scenario (you need to remember to remove it from the union as well, select * does it for you) and for the addition scenario, fail-fast ain't that bad (in my use case :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of columns would not change, the CTE "inherits" the metadata for the ordinal position.
Think of a CTE in this case as a regular view, views have their ordinal positions too.

Comment: You should cite a documentation reference here which confirms your answer.

Comment: As far as I’m aware, the fact that a column has an ordinal position does not guarantee the order in a SELECT * query. Unless there is definitive confirmation from the DBMS vendor then you shouldn’t rely on this and should explicitly list your columns - assuming the order matters

Comment: @NickW the answer linked in my OP makes a compelling case for it - so long as a vendor adheres to the ANSI specifications.

Comment: Possibly - but if your code is reliant on column order then I would always explicitly list the columns in the required order as then you have a definite guarantee. Taking an extra few minutes to do this seems a better approach than hoping/assuming that your DBMS adheres to the ANSI specification and/or that some other part of your code doesn’t mean that the ANSI specification doesn’t apply when you assumed it did